# Optimization of Take-Profit and Stop-Loss

Tags: optimization

Three questions:

1. What branch of mathematics would help me optimize profit if I have a trading strategy that on an individual trade basis (Trade 1, Trade 2, ..., Trade N) has a draw down of (X1,X2,...Xn) ticks and a profit for each trade of (Y1,Y2,..., Yn) ticks? Maybe I should have a larger stop-loss and smaller take-profit to maximize win percentage or maybe I should take smaller losses and bigger gains? I'm asking assuming I have specific data for X and Y values.
2. Now that I know which branch of mathematics I would need to know, what is the formula or algorithm to determine the stop-loss and take-profit that I should use each time?
3. What is the answer to questions 1 and 2 if I would want to know how to include in an algorithm or formula a potential Take-Profit that I come up with for each trade. For example, let's say that I project that for Trade 1 the potential profit is P1 and for Trade N the potential profit is Pn. Maybe the algorithm will say to ignore that piece of information and take Z ticks each time or maybe the algorithm will dictate a better actual-Take-Profit value if I include in that algorithm what I think my profit could be.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this: How do I optimize MAE and MFE?

Comment: MAE = Maximum Adverse Excursion, MFE = Maximum Favorable Excursion

Answer (score 3):

To answer question one: Operations Research would help you with this topic.

**Updated:**

Stochastic Processes is also a good course to take.

There is a very good paper titled: [Determining Optimal Trading Rules without Backtesting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1159)

It shows how to determine TP and SL levels using synthetic data.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. I am currently in the process of teaching myself linear algebra. i'd like to know a course of study so that I can continue to learn myself and advance to learning Operations Research. Can you tell me what subjects to learn? I can read the textbooks myself...

Comment: We made use of this book at university: "Introduction to Mathematical Programming: Volume 1: Applications and Algorithms" by Wayne L. Winston, M. A. Venkataramanan. It may not be the best book but it is a good book.

Comment: May I humbly add that I can't believe such a question doesn't have an obvious answer. I apologise in advance if this sounds conceited, but it comes up so much in finance. It is incredibly common. I am also commenting on order to boost viewers...

Comment: I don't follow the first statement. How can a trade have a drawdown and a profit at the same time ? thanks.

Comment: It might start with a drawdown and then go to profit.

Answer (score 1):

the way I see it, there isn't much to optimise about stoploss/takeprofit for the following simple reasoning:

- imagine you devised a trade strategy that on average builds up profit
- you can think of your trades as random walks with positive drift. That is, you can break each trade into a series of steps (e.g. steps of 1 minute duration). Each step yields a little profit distributed like $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, with $\mu>0$. All steps add up into your overall trade profit. So after $n$ steps your trade profit is distributed like $N(n \mu,n \sigma^2 )$. Basic math, does this make sense?
- now, your trade profit after $n$ steps will be $n \mu > 0$ on average, but in some cases it could be painfully negative! At that point, you will ask yourself *"am I better off to stop here or to continue?"*
- well if you *still* trust that your steps are i.i.d like $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, you should continue, because the math tells you that after further $k$ steps you will be on average $k\mu$ better off than now. Right?
- the same applies for the limit. Intuitively, why should you stop at step $n$ if you expect that after after 1 step you will be $\mu$ better off than now?
- of course, if you don't trust your trading strategy anymore, that's another story. It's not about stoploss/takprofit, I leave it off here for simplicity.
- so in theory, if you trust your trading strategy, the optimial values are stoploss=$-∞$ and takeprofit=$+∞$
- in practise, nobody prevents you from setting takeprofitt=$+∞$, but you can't have stoploss=$-∞$ because you have limited capital. If you don't set a stoploss barrier, your broker will set it for you equal to all of your capital (with some extra safety margin).
- so how do you set your stoploss in practice? Look at the money management theory for this. Spoiler: there is no no optimal value. It depends on your greed VS risk aversion.
- a quick example (study money management for more!). If you set stoploss=100% of your initial capital, you will be wiped out if the first trade goes bad, but if you are plain lucky you will enjoy a huge ROI. On the contrary, if you set stoploss=1% of your initial capital, you are much less likely to be ruined, but on average you get 100 times worse ROI than the "all-in" case.

Answer (score 0):

marketinout.com has a stop loss optimisation tool that calculates the stop loss, trailing stop and take profit % in increments you set , based on the strategy you input. It outputs 1000 calculations sorted by the parameters with the most profit for the set time frame.
https://www.marketinout.com/stock-screener/backtest/optimization/maintenance.php

Comment: Another area where you will find relevant literature is in "stochastic optimal control". If you google for a combination of that and "stop-loss" material should come up. Of course, the relevant  literature will assume that you're somewhat familiar with stochastic optimal control which is a huge field in itself. Good luck.